# How to Extract Strings from Text

Tags: flutter, dart

Lets Say this is My Text. Now I want to Extract All 4 Variable Separately from the text

"ScanCode=?  scanMsg= ? ItemName=? ID=  ?\n"

Please Help i need this is Dart, Flutter

Comment: do you mean getting `ScanCode`...?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I developed first splits the data according to the space character. It then uses the `GetValue()` method to sequentially read the data from each piece. The next step will be to use the data by transforming it accordingly.

This example prints the following output to the console:

```
[ScanCode=1234, ScanMessage=Test, Itemname=First, ID=1]
[1234, Test, First, 1]
```

The solution I developed is available below:

```dart
void main()
{
   String text = "ScanCode=1234 ScanMessage=Test ItemName=First ID=1";
   
   List<String> original = text.split(' ');
   List<String> result = [];
   
   GetValue(original, result);
   print(original);
   print(result);
}

void GetValue(List<String> original, List<String> result)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < original.length ; ++i)
    {
        result.insert(i, original[i].split('=')[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hurryyyyy ...Thanks Man You Saved My Life.

Comment: You're welcome. Please [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to find out the flow on Stack Overflow.